# Haskell how to add together every second element of tuples in a list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I would like to make a function that adds together the second element of every tuple in a list.
So far I have:

```
pizza :: [(String, Int)] -> Int
pizza [] = 0
pizza (((a),b):xs) = b + pizza xs
```

This works great but I come into a problem when i want to add another int after the recursion is done.

So what I get is:

```
> pizza[("Cheese",10),("Dough",5)]
15
```

I want to add another five after the recursion is done so I would get:

```
> pizza[("Cheese",10),("Dough",5)] 
20
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Just define a helper of type `[(String, Int)] -> [Int]`, then use `sum`.

Comment: If `pizza` is supposed to add 5 to a result, it's not the function you want to make recursive.

Comment: Or perhaps, `pizza [] = 5` is sufficient; does an empty list represent a valid pizza, or is it just a natural base case for the recursion?

Comment: Or even, `pizza list n` as a call, and then `pizza [] n = n`.

Comment: Given *only* the information in this question, the way I would go about doing this is `5 + pizza [("Cheese",10), ("Dough",5)]`. But given a bit of world knowledge, probably the way I'd go about it is `pizza [("Cheese", 10), ("Dough", 5), ("Labor", 5)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the recursion and work with a `map` instead:

```
pizza :: Num b => [(a, b)] -> b
pizza = (5 +) . sum . map snd
```

or more verbose:

```
pizza :: Num b => [(a, b)] -> b
pizza xs = 5 + (sum (map snd xs))
```

Answer (score 3):

If an empty list of ingredients is supposed to yield `5` anyway, you can simply reflect this in your base case.

```
pizza :: [(String, Int)] -> Int
pizza [] = 5
pizza (((a),b):xs) = b + pizza xs
```

On the other hand, if this only occurs when the list passed in is not empty, you can create a helper function that adds the `5` as its base case for recursion, but the helper only gets used when the list passed in is non-empty.

```
pizza :: [(String, Int)] -> Int
pizza [] = 0
pizza lst = pizza' lst
  where
    pizza' [] = 5
    pizza' ((_, x):xs) = x + pizza' xs
```

Now calling `pizza []` will yield `0`, but `pizza [("Cheese",10),("Dough",5)]` will yield `20`.

It is possibly to simplify `pizza'`. [Willem Van Onsem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74185404/15261315) has some great directions on this.